# How can I run an c/c++ program that use GNU Scientific Library (GSL)?

Tags: programming, c++, libraries, c, shared-library

I'm trying to run 2 simple examples in **c/c++** using the **GNU Scientific Library**.

That are the codes:

1st: [An Example Program](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/An-Example-Program.html)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h>

int main (void)
{
  double x = 5.0;
  double y = gsl_sf_bessel_J0 (x);
  printf ("J0(%g) = %.18e\n", x, y);
  return 0;
}
```

2nd:
**Example programs for matrices**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>

int main (void)
{
  int i, j; 
  gsl_matrix * m = gsl_matrix_alloc (10, 3);

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
      gsl_matrix_set (m, i, j, 0.23 + 100*i + j);

  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)  /* OUT OF RANGE ERROR */
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
      printf ("m(%d,%d) = %g\n", i, j, 
              gsl_matrix_get (m, i, j));

  gsl_matrix_free (m);

  return 0;
}
```

I saw on the **Software Center** that I have the ***GNU Scientific Library (GSL) - Library package (libgsl0ldbl 1.16+dfsg-1ubuntu1)*** but the documentation that I read said that I needed to compile with the next code:

```
$ gcc -Wall -I/usr/local/include -c example.c
```

And directory `/usr/local/include` was empty so recently I have also installed manually from the site [Main GSL - GNU Scientific Library site](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gsl/) the new version **GSL2.1**. Next I run the code before mentioned so I had a new file example.o then I run the next code:

```
$ gcc -L/usr/local/lib example.o -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

So I had a `a.out` file, I tried to run `$ ./a.out` but the output was:

```
`./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libgsl.so.19: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
```

I tried this command too:

```
$ ldconfig -p | grep gsl
    libgslcblas.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgslcblas.so.0
    libgsl.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgsl.so.0
```

So I can see that the excecution of `a.out` was asking for `libgsl.so.19` but the ldconfig said that the library on the pc is `libgsl.so.19`

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 has `libgsl.so.19` in the `libgsl2` package. But if you've installed manually, check if `sudo ldconfig` helps to update the library lookup cache or try to specify the search path manually when launching: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib ./a.out`

Comment: Try:   `sudo apt-get install gsl-bin`  and then 
         `gcc example.c -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm`

Comment: Thank you guys! @Velkan, I can solve this problem with `sudo ldconfig`.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the path of library and exporting it, this is a dirty way but it works

1. LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/data2/Irfan/gsl/lib
2. export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

note* /data2/Irfan/gsl/lib is a path of where you have installed gsl

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem might have been solved now. This answer will provide easy reference for anyone who might have faced the similar issue.

Apart from Irfan solution which is a perfectly valid solution. Another option is to link static library at the time of linking.

`gcc -L/usr/local/lib example.o -l:libgsl.a -lgslcblas -lm`